# Solr fq (Filter Query) parameter in Sitefinity CMS

Tags: solr, sitefinity, solrnet

I am using Solrnet in my Sitefinity CMS, I am also using it for filtering purposes, for example in my list View of my Events. In my Events, I have a custom field of Choices type and in my Solr Search Results view, I would like to exclude those events that are a selected as "Interest Group". I thought using the fq parameter like this would do the trick, by the way, **EventType** is the name of my custom field in Sitefinity:

```
fq=-b_cms_EventType:("Interest Group")
```

But this doesn't work for me. Interest Group the type of event I would like excluded. I used a similar kind of filter in another View to only display my Interest Group events and this worked for me:

```
fq=sm_cms_EventType:("Interest Group")
```

But why the same concept isn't working for excluding with `fq=-b_`?

If it helps, the debug log in the page that is only displaying my Interest Group events is this:

```
https://solr.mywebsite.com:2664/solr/sf-site/select?q=*%3a*&start=0&rows=50&fq=(resourceType%3a((event)))&fq=dt_cms_EventEnd%3a%5bNOW+TO+*%5d&fq=sm_cms_EventType%3a(%22Interest+Group%22)&facet=true&facet.field=sm_cms_EventType&facet.field=sm_cms_Region&facet.field=taxonomyIds&facet.field=resourceType&wt=xml&sort=sortableDate+asc
```

Comment: Is the value of Interest Group option same as the label?

Comment: Hi @VeselinVasilev, the value is "interest-group". I tried with that too but that didn't help either, I tried this fq=-b_cms_EventType:("interest-group")